# Why document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d'). hasOwnProperty('font') returns false?

Tags: javascript, canvas

Why does `hasOwnProperty('font')` returns false while the returned object has this property.

```js
var ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
console.log(ctx.hasOwnProperty('font'));
console.log(ctx.font);
```

Here is a screenshot of the keys of document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d'), where we can see it has a `font` property.
[image: A screenshot of a console log where indeed the font property is logged as well as other properties of the CanvasRenderingContext2D object]

Comment: Because `font` is a property of the CanvasRenderingContext2D prototype, hence not an OwnProperty of your context instance.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's because `font` isn't a simple property of the context, but rather a getter and setter function pair.

Comment: It is indeed, but that's not why hasOwnProperty returns false, or at least, not by itself.

Comment: It's current,because document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d') is a object has none of keys.

Comment: @梁家辉 yes but this answer is correct in that this property is a getter/setter functions pair, so when you call its getter, it will return its own, internal value, and when you set it, it will set its own internal value, but the property in itself is not the value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get & https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set